# mod_rewrite: "%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" always true

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I try to serve some legacy images if the new images sizes have not been created.

My problem is, that the legacy versions do always get served, even when the new versions are present.

Example:

- foobar.png => is present
- n1_foobar.png => is NOT present
- b_foobar.png => is present
- b2_foobar.png => is present

All the files are in "/sub/dir/123/". "123" can change depending on page served.

It works in means that "foobar.png" is served then i request "n1_foobar.png".
But it also does serve "b1_foobar.png " when i request "b2_foobar.png" while it should not.

I guess i am missing some flags?

this is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\/n1_(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\/b2_(.*)$ $1/b_$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

**solved:**

since i was adding the rules to my virtualhost-configuration and not a ".htaccess" i was missing "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}"

this is the fixed ruleset which works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/n1_(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/b2_(.*)$ $1/b_$2 [L]
```

edit: added directory info1
edit: solved my own stupidity(is there a way to delete embarrassing questions?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified version.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/n1_(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/b2_(.+)$ /$1/b_$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: also if i move the files to the root directory your solution does not work. "n1_foobar.jpg" is not served by "foobar.jpg" when missing.

Comment: What exactly is full URL of your images?

Comment: "/a/1452542/b2_foobar.jpg", "/a/1452542/b_foobar.jpg" and "/a/1452542/foobar.jpg".  Not present is "/a/1452542/n1_foobar.jpg" which is what i am trying to rewrite.